# MongoDB database on git repository

Tags: git, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm preparing a git repository for me and my friend's fun project learning to make an images/videos sharing website. We're learning the MEAN stack along the way. Now only I have set up MongoDB */data/db* and have been playing around with it.

The question is that, should I/can I make a *data/db* folder in the git repo so my friend can pull everything and see the images displaying on his browser? Or should I be the only one working on the database?

Also, any tips or advice on deploying are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I strongly discourage putting DB data files under git. Share those files through other file sharing mechanisms (rsync, dropbox, gdrive, etc..). Git is not the right place for this. If you guys are collaborating on the data also (not just on the code), then use a file sharing solution which supports versions. I am not a 100% sure but I think Dropbox and GDrive both support versioning.

Comment: @brahmana Using dropbox is not a good idea either. When both are writing to the database at the same time, the file sharing program will run into edit conflicts. When it tries to resolve them automatically in favor of either instance, the database might get corrupted. This once happened to me when I tried to share a MongoDB dev database between my desktop and my notebook.

Comment: @Philipp Indeed. Sorry I did not consider the auto-sync feature. What I meant to say was share the DB files using Dropbox/GDrive whenever needed. Having the MongoDB data directory under Dropbox/GDrive is definitely not good. A cleaner way would of course be sharing bson dumps.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, it could work. You can put your MongoDB database files under version control. When you commit the database files while MongoDB isn't running and your colleague pulls them while his MongoDB instance isn't running either, it should be possible to exchange the database content this way. At least as long as you are both using the same version of MongoDB.

However, it might not be a good idea to do this, because Git isn't built for large binary files which change often. Your repository might not perform as well as you would expect it from Git.

As an alternative solution, you could set up one MongoDB instance which you both access in parallel via network.

Comment: ...like a hosted MongoDB database from Compose, MongoLab,... (free for really small DBs)